# excel numeric value for text in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can someone help me with a formula to assign a numeric value for a text cell, then total the number at the end of the row?

Y=1, then add all the 1's in the row.  I am trying to get total number of certifications per employee

[example of worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKgzT.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use a COUNTIF formula.

Cell F2 formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:E2,"Y")
```

Drag it down, done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I was over thinking it...lol